# Isometries in $\Bbb R^2$ are linear

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

I'm trying to prove that isometries $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ are linear (usual Euclidean metric). It is assumed that $T(0)=0$.

I think that I have proved that $T(\alpha v)=\alpha T(v)$, but I'm having problems with sum.

> **Context:**
>
> I have defined $\Bbb R^2$ as a set of points and a set of free
> vectors.The dot product is like that $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=ac+bd$ and the
> module of a vector $v$ is $\sqrt{v\cdot v}$. I have defined lines as
> set of points $\{P+t\vec v:t\in\Bbb R\}$. I have managed to prove
> triangular inequality. Just that.

My idea is proving that
$$\|Tu+Tv-T(u+v)\|^2=0$$ but I get dot products like $Tu\cdot T(u+v)$. I have tried other expresions like $$\|T(u+v)-Tu\|^2,$$ getting the same problem.

On the other hand, the trick
$$u\cdot v=\frac12\left(\|u+v\|^2-\|u\|^2-\|v\|^2\right)$$ leads me to a circular reasoning, bacause I have to compute $T(u+v)$.

Any ideas?

*Note:* I can't deal with continuity in $\Bbb R^2$. This is for a High School student.

Comment: And maybe this [Mazur-Ulam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem)

Comment: The problem that proving that isometries preserves inner productos is still there. And I haven't proved yet that the are surjective. In fact, this is the goal...

Comment: You can write the inner product in terms of norms using the polarization identity, and so that implies that isometries preserve the inner product.

Comment: @memerson So... $$Tu\cdot Tv=\frac12\left(\|Tu+Tv\|^2-|Tu\|^2-\|Tv\|^2\right)$$ and what should I do with $\|Tu+Tv\|^2$?

Answer (score 0):

From $T(0)=0$ and $\|Tu-Tv\|=\|u-v\|$ we have $\|Tu\|=\|u\|$ and $\langle Tu,Tv\rangle=\langle u,v\rangle$, that is, $T$ is orthogonal.

Let $(a_1,a_2)$ an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^2$, then $ (Ta_1, Ta_2)$ is an orthonormal basis as well.  Now
$$\begin{align}
Tp&=\langle Ta_1,Tp\rangle Ta_1+\langle Ta_2,Tp\rangle Ta_2\\
&=\langle a_1,p\rangle Ta_1+\langle a_2,p\rangle Ta_2.
\end{align}
$$